# Kubernetes OpenSearch Deployment | "no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set" error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, opensearch

We deployed OpenSearch using Kubernetes according documentation instructions on 3 nodes cluster (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/install/helm/) , after deployment pods are on Pending state and when checking it, we see following msg:
"
persistentvolume-controller no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
"
Can you please advise what could be wrong in our OpenSearch/Kubernetes deployment or what can be missing from configuration perspective?

**sharing some info**:

**Cluster nodes:**

```
[root@I***-M1 ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION
ir***-m1 Ready control-plane,master 4h34m v1.23.4
ir***-w1 Ready 3h41m v1.23.4
ir***-w2 Ready 3h19m v1.23.4
```

**Pods State:**

```
[root@I****1 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
opensearch-cluster-master-0 0/1 Pending 0 80m
opensearch-cluster-master-1 0/1 Pending 0 80m
opensearch-cluster-master-2 0/1 Pending 0 80m


[root@I****M1 ~]# kubectl describe pvc
Name:          opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-deployment
               app.kubernetes.io/name=opensearch
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       opensearch-cluster-master-0
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                       From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                      ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  2m24s (x18125 over 3d3h)  persistentvolume-controller  **no persistent 
  volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set**
  .....

[root@IR****M1 ~]# kubectl get pv
NAME                                                    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM 
POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0   30Gi       RWO            Retain          Available           manual                  6h24m
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-1   30Gi       RWO            Retain               Available           manual                  6h22m
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-2   30Gi       RWO            Retain          Available           manual                  6h23m
task-pv-volume                                          60Gi       RWO            Retain   Available           manual                  7h48m       


[root@I****M1 ~]# kubectl get pvc
NAME                                                    STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS  MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0   Pending   3d3h                                                 
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-1   Pending   3d3h                                                   
opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-2   Pending   3d3h
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...no storage class is set...

Try upgrade your deployment with storage class, presumed you run on AWS EKS: `helm upgrade my-deployment opensearch/opensearch --set persistence.storageClass=gp2`

If you are running on GKE, change `gp2` to `standard`. On AKS change to `default`.

Comment: "persistence.storageClass" isn't a valid value. https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/opensearch-project-helm-charts/opensearch?modal=values

Comment: It's still valid despite the answer is > 1 year. See it at line 210 with the link in your comment.